# ROR - How to update a rubygem to a particular version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to update a gem version to a particular version. But whenever I run command `bundle update gem`, it is updating the latest version of that gem.

Even on running command `bundle update gem -v "x.x.x"`  it is still updating to the latest one.

Is there any way to update a gem version to a particular version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Gemfile specify the gem version. For example:

```
gem "foo", "= 1.0.0"
```

then run `bundle update foo`